# Chat Server with Python Socket Server and Android Client

Tags: python, android, sockets

I am trying to create a simple Chat Server that runs on Python.I am having difficulties in getting a connection between my Android App and my Python Socket Server. I am not getting any response so I dont really know what the problem is. The output is:

Socket created
Socket Bind Success!
Socket is now listening

After that there is nothing else coming.

Here is the Python Server:

```
import socket
import sys

HOST = "1.2.3.4"
PORT = 1234

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print('socket created')

# Bind socket to Host and Port
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as err:
    print("Bind Failed, Error Code: ") + str(err[0]) + ', Message: ' + err[1]
    sys.exit()

print("Socket Bind Success!")

# listen(): This method sets up and start TCP listener.
s.listen(10)
print("Socket is now listening")

while 1:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print
    'Connect with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])
    buf = conn.recv(64)
    print
    buf
s.close()
```

and here are two classes from my Android App (My client):

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.client;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText inputMessage = findViewById(R.id.inputMessage);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new SendMessage().execute(inputMessage.getText().toString());
                inputMessage.getText().clear();
            }
        });



    }
}
```

SendMessage.java:

```
package com.example.client;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private Exception exception;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket("1.2.3.4",1234);
                PrintWriter outToServer = new PrintWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(
                                socket.getOutputStream()));
                outToServer.print(params[0]);
                outToServer.flush();


            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            this.exception = e;
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The idea and the layout of the app is, that I have a field where I can write text in and send it by hitting the send button.

I tried paying around with the host and the port but I still got no response. I checked if the networks are able to communicate with eachother. The notebook where the server runs is connected via LAN and the Smartphone which runs the app is connected to a Wifi network. Both of them seem to be able to communicate with eachother.

Comment: What are the IP addresses? It seems likely that `1.2.3.4` is "made up" and hence not correct. Your server as coded above will only work if the network interface through which it is being reached actually has the IP address 1.2.3.4. It is common to have the server listen on 0.0.0.0 (which listens to all IP addresses on the local host). But you'll still need to know the server's IP address on the client side in order for it to reach the server. (Typically you would run `ifconfig`, `ipconfig` or `ip addr` [depending on platform] on the server to discover its IP address.)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick answer. Yes the ip addresses are made up. I used the ip address i found in the windows settings under my ethernet. I copied the ipv4 address and pasted it in both the server and the client. Greetings

Comment: It's not clear to me what your comment is saying: you had already done that before the original post? Or you did that *after* my comment? If the latter, did it solve your problem? It seems to me the basic problem you're having is in addressing the server host from the client host -- which is more a networking problem that a coding problem per se. I would approach this by first making sure that you can ping the server system from the client system using the same server IP address. Once you have that working, proceed to trying your code.

Comment: Also, is your client getting any error message? I would expect the `Socket("1.2.3.4",1234)` call to fail, either immediately or after a timeout. The error / stack trace produced would be helpful in troubleshooting.

Comment: Hello, sorry for not making it clear. I already used the correct IP addresses for both of them before your comment. I just changed the ip addresses for safety reasons. I tried another chat server and wanted to check if I even get a connection between the two sides. It was a basic chat server with some html text. I then tried to open the page in the internet browser and got the information that the server recieves a connection from the phone. So apparently its not the connection between the two. In the first paragraph of my question I wrote the output I got.

Comment: The socket server is listening the whole time but doesnt show that the phone is connected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not the brightest and forgot to add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

in my AndroidManifest.xml

Now it works :)